# Angular problem: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am pretty new with Angular and I stuck with problem building up my portfolio project. The problem is with receiving list of (nested) objects like this:

```
    "$id": "1",
    "data": {
        "$id": "2",
        "$values": [
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "id": 1,
                "name": "producto",
                "shortDescription": "prod11111",
                "longDescription": "lorem ipsum bla bla",
                "category": "1",
                "price": 50.00,
                "stockLevel": 10,
                "orderDetails": {
                    "$id": "4",
                    "$values": []
                }
            },
            {
                "$id": "5",
                "id": 2,
                "name": "segundo",
                "shortDescription": "prod222",
                "longDescription": "lorem ipsum",
                "category": "2",
                "price": 30.00,
                "stockLevel": 20,
                "orderDetails": {
                    "$id": "6",
                    "$values": []
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "error": null
}
```

This is my app.component.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Shop';
  products: any[] = [];
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/api/products').subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.products = response.data;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

This is app.component.html:

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 140px;">
    <h1>Welcome to {{title}}!</h1>
    <ul>  
        <li class="list-unstyled" *ngFor="let product of products">
            {{product.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I looked thru StackOverflow for similar problems but cannot resolve this in my case.
I think that there is problem because of arrays of arrays or nested objects.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `response.data` is not an array.  I think you want `response.data.$values`.  so do `this.products = response.data.$values;`

Comment: @BizzyBob How did you know so fast the correct answer?
What gives that '$values'?  
Huge thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response.data` is not an array. Instead, I believe that `response.data.$values` is what you need for the `products` array.

```js
this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/api/products').subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.products = response.data.$values;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Wow, unbelievable, how did you know so fast the correct answer?
What gives that '$values'?  
Big thanks!